# How to Force Vertx Rx CodeGen To Generate MayBe As Return Type

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, vert.x, rx-kotlin, codegen

I am using following Kotlin code to generate proxy (This will also generate Rx methods)

```
@ProxyGen
@VertxGen
interface JobService {
    @Fluent
    fun getCertain(jobId: Int, handler: Handler<AsyncResult<Job?>>): JobService
}
```

When I see generated Rx Code it is as follows.

```
public Single<Job> rxGetCertain(int jobId) { 
   return new io.vertx.reactivex.core.impl.AsyncResultSingle<Job>(handler -> {
     getCertain(jobId, handler);
   });
}
```

**Issue:-**

Unfortunately i am not able to use this in Kotlin as kotlin won't allow null values for non-null fields and it is throwing following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null
```

How do i force Vertx CodeGen to generate return type as MayBe so that my code works without any issues in kotlin.

Comment: Can you try to mark the async result type with `@Nullable`?

Comment: i tried that before, unfortunately it's giving the same output.

Comment: Could you please create a bug report in https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-codegen ?

Comment: Done Created [https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-codegen/issues/200](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-codegen/issues/200)

Answer (score 0):

Add annonation @Nullable

```
@ProxyGen
@VertxGen
interface JobService {
    @Fluent
    fun getCertain(jobId: Int, handler: Handler<AsyncResult<@Nullable Job?>>): JobService
}
```

Comment: As specified in one of my previous replies, i tried that and it is not working. https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-kotlin/issues/71